# Comparing value of two array, while property value is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of arrays. The sort is working function, unless when the property value is undefined.

For example:

posts array =

{id: "1", content: "test", "likes":[{"user_id":"2","user_name":"test"}] },

{id: "2", content: "test", "likes":[{"user_id":"2","user_name":"test"}, 
{"user_id:"3", "user_name":"tea"}] },

{id: "3", content: "test"}

When I try to sort the array using below function:

posts.sort((a,b) => {return (b.likes.length ) -(a.likes.length) })

It is working fine, if there is no array with (likes.lenghth) as undefined.

However, when the third array is included, I am getting the error (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined).

Is there is a way to still sort the array in this way, while the parameter is still missing is some of the arrays?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where almost there. You can simply default to an empty array if the attribute is not present (falsy to be exact).

```js
const posts = [
  {id: "1", content: "test", likes: [{user_id: "2", user_name: "test"}]},
  {id: "2", content: "test", likes: [{user_id: "2", user_name: "test"}, 
                                     {user_id: "3", user_name: "tea" }]},
  {id: "3", content: "test"}
];

console.log(
  posts.sort((a, b) => (b.likes || []).length - (a.likes || []).length)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to be explicit within your sort function as to how to handle those scenarios. Here's a simplified example that uses a short-circult expression to test whether `a.likes` and `b.likes` exist.

```js
const posts = [{ likes: [1] }, { likes: [1, 2, 3]}, {}];

posts.sort((a, b) => {
  const aLikes = a.likes ? a.likes.length : 0;
  const bLikes = b.likes ? b.likes.length : 0;
  return bLikes - aLikes;
});

console.log(posts);
```

Comment: While this doesn't throw an error due to the short-circuit nature. Keep in mind that `const aLikes = a.likes && a.likes.length;` sets `aLikes` to `undefined` if `a` doesn't posses the `likes` attribute. The same for `b`. Resulting in a return value of `NaN` for anything compared to a post without likes.

Comment: thanks buddy for your input...I am afraid this didn't work out in my repo

Answer (score 0):

I think just validating the object is not undefined and returning a min/max value when the condition be false.

```
posts.sort((a,b) => {
   if(b.likes && a.likes)
     return (b.likes.length ) -(a.likes.length)
   else
     return -1;//min value or max value 
});
```

OR

```
posts.sort((a,b) => {       
     return (b.likes && a.likes)?(b.likes.length ) -(a.likes.length):-1
   }
);
```

Comment: thanks buddy for your input...I am afraid this didn't work out in my repo